# Singular value decomposition inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Assume $A$ is nonsingular with SVD i.e \begin{equation}
A = U \Sigma V^{T}
\end{equation}

$U,V$ orthogonal.

$\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries $ \Sigma= diag (\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{2}, . . . , \sigma_{r})$  and $\sigma_1 ≥ \sigma_2 ≥\ldots ≥ \sigma_r> 0$  are  the  positive  singular  values   of  $A$.

Prove that

$\sigma_{n} \| x \| _{2} \leq \|Ax\|_{2} ≤ \sigma_{1}\|x\|_{2}$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to notice that, since $U $ and $V $ are orthogonal, $$\|Ax\|_2=\|\Sigma (V^Tx)\|_2\ \ \ \text {and } \ \ \|V^Tx\|_2=\|x\|_2 $$

Comment: That should be $\|Ax\| = \|\Sigma(V^Tx)\|$, and of course $\|V^Tx\| = \|x\|$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. $ $